# Can the ancients do lifeleech?

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-barbarian

I have, on my barbarian, the ability Bloodthisrt (3% of damage converted to life) with the spell Call of the ancients.

Do the hits made by the ancients restore some of my life or are the ancients damage not considered as my own?

Comment: Might be vaguely applicable, but my Hydra damaging mobs with the Reflect Damage affix damages me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No the Extra barbs do not give/ get you any hp from the bloodthirt passive skill

Comment: More details would be needed to consider this as an answer (sources?)